# Angular - Have input save to variables in factory to be used elsewhere

Tags: angularjs, factory, angular-services

I'm creating a single page application and need to be able to display input from one template onto another. The way I have my factory currently set up is not working. Can someone help with this?

Factory:

```
angular.module('BSG').factory('airplaneFactory', function() {
    var name = '';
    var last_name = '';
    var color = '';

    function setData(n, ln, c) {
        name = n;
        last_name = ln;
        color = c;
    }

    return {
        name: name,
        last_name: last_name,
        color: color,
        setData: setData
    }
})
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('BSG').controller('AirplaneCtrl', ['$scope', 'airplaneFactory', function($scope, airplaneFactory) {
    'use strict';

    function updateFactory() {
        airplaneFactory.setData($scope.name, $scope.last_name, $scope.color);
    }

}]);
```

Snippet from template where input is gathered:

```
<h2>Who is this story about?</h2>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="name" ng-change="updateFactory()"></p>

<h2>What is {{ name }}'s last name?</h2>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="last name" ng-model="last_name" ng-change="updateFactory()"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because there is no two-way binding in `$scope.name = airplaneFactory.name;`. That simply writes the factory property value into a scope variable.

To save data in your factory, you can create a setter function:

```
angular.module('BSG').factory('airplaneFactory', function() {
    var name = '';
    var last_name = '';
    var color = '';

    function setData(n, ln, c) {
        name = n;
        last_name = ln;
        color = c;
    }

    return {
        name: name,
        last_name: last_name,
        color: color,
        setData: setData
    }
})
```

And since the services are singletons, the data will remain the same on different controllers.

So to set the data from a controller, you'd do something like this:

```
airplaneFactory.setData('John', 'Doe', 'red');
```

To have the factory updates happen automatically, you should set $watchers on the controller scope properties or use onchange listeners on your input elements. For example:

```
<h2>Who is this story about?</h2>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="name" ng-change="updateFactory()"></p>

<h2>What is {{ name }}'s last name?</h2>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="last name" ng-model="last_name" ng-change="updateFactory()"></p>
```

And then in the controller you'd have the updateFactory function which will call the factory setData method:

```
function updateFactory() {
    airplaneFactory.setData($scope.name, $scope.last_name, $scope.color);
}
```

---

UPDATE

Here is a Plunker where everything is working, I've added a button to fetch the latest data from the factory, so you can test it: http://plnkr.co/edit/JQd22tEYSPuJwutCLH1B?p=preview

Don't forget that all ng-* attributes are working with scope properties, so:

```
function updateFactory() {...
```

won't be enough, since you need to have a scope property with that name:

```
$scope.updateFactory = updateFactory;
```

Or simply define the whole function like I did in the Plunker example:

```
$scope.updateFactory = function() {... etc
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the factory as a dependency in your controller, so you have access to it.

Comment: @Shomz Would I also need to create some sort of submit button that triggers this update? The way I have things set up now still isn't working. I've updated my code in the original question to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: No need for a submit button - ng-change should handle it. Let me write a live example and see what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Use rootScope to access name, last_name and color in every view and controller (inject the $rootScoope...

Comment: That is an option, however since we have a dedicated service (and services are singletons), there's no need to have the same data in two places.